# Collect as HashMap<String,String> from a List or Stream of objects without a POJO in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects out of which I have to create a `HashMap<String,String>` or `ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>` after applying certain logic on each of the objects in the list. Here is the code which works perfectly fine without using java 8.

```
 for (Model model : parser.getList()) {
       String name = model.getName();
       String val = parser.getValue(arr, name);
       map.putIfAbsent(name, val);
 }
```

I was able to translate it as

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
parser.getList().forEach(model -> map.putIfAbsent(model.getName(),parser.getValue(arr,model.getName())));
```

However I wanted to explore the usage of `Collectors.toMap` and see if I can leverage that for this use case. I was trying to do something like below but that isn't the correct usage as I am unable to call the method **parser.getValue** with params in `toMap()`.

```
 Map<String,String> valMap = parser.getFieldList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Model::getName,parser.getValue(arr,Model::getName),(left,right)->right),HashMap::new);
```

I was able to use `Collectors.toMap()` when I created a POJO ValHolder to hold the values as below.

```
Map<String,String> tranMap = parser.getFieldList().stream().map(model -> {
        return new ValHolder(model.getName(),parser.Value(dataArray,model.getName()));
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(ValHolder::getName,ValHolder::getValue,(x,y)->y,HashMap::new));
```

The POJO created to hold the value is as below

```
class ValHolder {

    String name;
    String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    ValHolder(String name, String val){
        fieldName = name;
        value = val;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if `toMap()` can be used without creating a POJO to hold the values to be accessible easily via Method references.

Comment: Side note: all versions of your code are computing and then discarding duplicates. At least the first two can avoid that by checking `map.containsKey` before even calling `parser.getValue`

Comment: If you could have noticed, the sequence of get, set and get of attributes, it would have been really simpler to identify the actual operation to perform for the result you were looking at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use a method reference.

For example:

```
Map<String,String> valMap = 
    parser.getFieldList()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Model::getName,
                                    m -> parser.getValue(arr,m.getName()),
                                    (left,right)->right,
                                    HashMap::new));
```

Or, you can use a `Map.Entry` implementation instead of your POJO:

```
Map<String,String> tranMap = 
    parser.getFieldList()
          .stream()
          .map(model -> new SimpleEntry<>(model.getName(),parser.getValue(dataArray,model.getName())))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    (x,y)->y,
                                    HashMap::new));
```

Comment: Converting to a `Map.Entry` before collecting to a `Map` should be unwanted! So, could the `HashMap::new` with the existing default implementation.

Comment: Based on `map.putIfAbsent(name, val);` it looks like OP wants to preserve first value placed in map for each key, so shouldn't `(left,right)->right` be `(left,right)->left`, or to make it more readable `(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue`?

Comment: @Pshemo well, it's possible that's what they wanted, but based on the OP's Stream pipelines, they seem to want to use the new value, so it's hard to tell which of the two options they really wanted.

Comment: OK. Fair enough.

Comment: Ironically, the only reason to insert an intermediate step would be to avoid redundant operations, like calling `model.getName()` twice, which is precisely what the OP did not. Besides that, I don’t see how `SimpleEntry` is not a POJO, it’s just an already existing class.